# Чат на socket.io — в чём ошибка?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сокет, socket.io

Пишу *чат*. После ввода ника ничего не происходит, страница просто перезагружается, хотя должна показать само окно *чата*.

Вот исходники:

Index.html

```
<body>
<div class="setNickname-wrap">
  <form class="nick-form">
    <input type="text" class="nickname">
    <!-- <input type="submit" class="add" value='Enter a nickname'> -->
    <input type='submit' class="add" value='Enter a nickname'>
  </form>
  <p class="nick-error"></p>
</div>


<div class="chat-wrap">
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
  <form class='send-message'>
    <input type="text" id="input" autocomplete="off">
    <input type='submit' class='send' value='Send'>
  </form>

  <div class="online-users"></div>
</div>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io(),
  sendMessage = $('.send-message'),
  nickWrap = $('.setNickname-wrap'),
  chatWrap = $('.chat-wrap'),
  nickInput = $('.nick'),
  nickForm = $('.nick-form'),
  nickError = $('.nick-error'),
  onlineUsers = $('online-users');

chatWrap.hide();
nickForm.submit(function(){
  socket.emit('new user', nickInput.val(), function(data){
    if(data){
      nickWrap.hide();
      chatWrap.show();
    } else {
      nickError.html("That username is already taken.");
    }
  });
  // nickInput.val('');
});

socket.on('usernames', function(data){
  var html = '';
  for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    html += data[i] + '<br>';
  }
  onlineUsers.html(html);
});

sendMessage.submit(function(){
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#input').val());
  $('#input').val('');
  return false;
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  // $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  $('#messages').append('<li><b>' + data.nick + ': </b>' + data.msg + '</li>' + '<br>');
});
</script>
</body>
```

server.js

```
var app = require('express')()
  http = require('http').Server(app),
  io = require('socket.io')(http),
  nicknames = [];

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('new user', function(data, callback){
    if(nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1){
      callback(false);
    } else {
      callback(true);
      socket.nickname = data;
      nicknames.push(socket.nickname);
      updateNicknames();
    }
  });

  function updateNicknames(){
    io.emit('usernames', nicknames);
  }

  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.emit('new message', {msg: data, nick: socket.nickname});
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
    if(!socket.nickname) return;
    nicknames.splice(nicknames.indexOf(socket.nickname), 1);
    updateNicknames();
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on 127.0.0.1:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно отменять стандартную отправку формы:

```
nickForm.submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```